# Bash printf multiple lines from arg in columns

Tags: bash, printf

I've been fiddling around with this for hours but can't get it to work, so maybe my approach is wrong.

I want to pretty-display multiple lines of a message, so the 'title' is to the left, and then the message aligns to that in a column, so for example, like:

```
WARNING: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
         How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!
```

or

```
NOTE: This happened.
      Foo bar.
```

and so on.

I'm trying to do this with `printf` and `column` based on some answers I could find, but as I say, maybe this approach can never work?

At the moment, I have the first string for `printf` as the 'title' and then the rest of the args are the message to align to that, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

warn() {
  printf '%s+%s\n' 'WARNING:' "${@}" | column --table --separator '+'
}

warn "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." \
     "+Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow." \
     "+How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!"
```

Can this be done similarly? Or what is the best way/some other way to do this?

#### Actual output:

```
WARNING:  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.    
          Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.            How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!
```

Comment: I'm assuming the `+` character is present in the other lines

Comment: try something like 

`warn() {   printf '%s %s\n' 'WARNING:' "${@}" | sed 's/+/\n         /g';}    `

(i.e. replace each + with "newline followed by 9 spaces...")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an implementation that requires no loop and no sub shell:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

taggedMessage() {
  # Prints first message with prepend tag
  printf '%s %s\n' "${1:?}" "${2:?}"

  [ $# -gt 2 ] || return # Returns if only one message

  # Constructs blank filler of same length as tag
  printf -v filler '%*s' ${#1} ''

  shift 2 # Shifts arguments at 2nd message

  # Prints remaining messages with prepend filler
  printf %s\\n "${@/#/$filler }"
}

warn() { taggedMessage 'WARNING:' "$@";}

warn "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." \
     "Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow." \
     "How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!"

taggedMessage 'SINGLE:' 'A single-line message.'

taggedMessage 'RANDOM TAG:' \
    "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." \
    "Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow." \
    "How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!"
```

Comment: Interesting use of parameter expansion! :+1:

Comment: Can you please tell me more about the printf line with the `%s\\n`? What's that doing? i.e why the double `\\`?

Comment: @nooblag `%s\\n` is same as `'%s\n'`. When omitting quotes  the backslash character must be escaped. In this specific format string case, the former syntax is one character shorter than the later.

Comment: One more question, and sorry for this. I put this to use on Bash 5.x and it works great, thank you! However I get the appearance of quote marks on a shared host running Cloudlinux 7 (Bash 4.2.46). https://postimg.cc/bDpqQdvb I wonder if there's something simple that could be done to solve backwards compatibility?

Comment: @nooblag replace `printf %s\\n "${@/#/"$filler "}"` by `printf %s\\n "${@/#/$filler }"` probably.

Answer (score 5):

If you remove the `column` pipeline, `printf '%s+%s\n' 'WARNING:' "${@}"` will produce:

```
WARNING:+The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
+Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.++How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!
```

This is how `printf` processed its input, according to the `%s+%s\n` specification:

- first pass:

  - first token is "WARNING:"
  - second token is "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
  - produces "WARNING:+The quick ... dog\n" and feed to `column`. All okay.
- second pass:

  - first token is "+Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow."
  - second token is "+How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!"
  - produces "+Sphinx of ... vow++How quickly ... vex!"
  - part "+Sphinx of ...." will correctly appear in the next row, in the second column
  - part "++How quickly ... vex!" will appear **in the same row (as "Sphinx ...")** (whereas it would be needed to move it to the next row below), in the **3rd column** (two "+" separators)

Here's a suggestion for your `warn` function:

```
warn() {
  local Title='WARNING'
  local Separator='+'
  local FirstArg="${1:-(default message)}"

  # if arguments were supplied, zap first one
  # and prepend SEPARATOR to remaining others
  if test "$#" -gt 0
     then shift
     for _ in "$@"
     do  set -- "$@" "${Separator}${1}"
         shift
     done
  fi

  printf '%s\n' "${Title}:${Separator}${FirstArg}" "$@" | column -t -s "${Separator}"
}
```

With an invocation like

```
warn "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." \
     "Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow." \
     "How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!"
```

... it will feed the following to `column`:

```
WARNING:+The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
+Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
+How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!
```

... which will ultimately be displayed like this:

```
WARNING:  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
          Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
          How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!
```

Tested as a `/bin/sh` script under Debian 11.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prtmsg() {
    local pfx="${FUNCNAME[1]^^}: " arg

    for arg; do
        printf '%s%s\n' "$pfx" "$arg" >&2
        pfx=${pfx//?/ }
    done
}

trace() { (( traceOn )) && prtmsg "$@"; }
note()    { prtmsg "$@"; }
warning() { prtmsg "$@"; }
error()   { prtmsg "$@"; }

warning 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' \
        'Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.' \
        'How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!'

error 'the sky is falling'

trace 'here we go again'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
WARNING: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
         How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!
ERROR: the sky is falling
```

```
$ traceOn=1 ./tst.sh
WARNING: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
         How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!
ERROR: the sky is falling
TRACE: here we go again
```

Comment: I love this. This is *elegant.*

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea of being able to pass in alternative labelling, but prefer to have a default that doesn't force me to do so.

```bash
warn() {
  local tag='WARNING' pad first
  case $1 in --*) tag=${1/#--/}; shift;; esac
  first=$1; shift;
  pad="${tag//?/ }  "; # add 2 for colon & space in 1st line
  printf "%s\n" "${tag^^}: $first" "${@/#/$pad}"
}
```

Now I can just call it and get the default WARNING label -

```
$: warn foo bar baz
WARNING: foo
         bar
         baz
```

or specify something else with a couple of leading dashes:

```
$: warn --error "Around the rugged rock" "The ragged rascal ran"
ERROR: Around the rugged rock
       The ragged rascal ran
```

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of Awk and Bash, you could define a function like below. Define an argument for the log level, `WARNING`, `INFO` etc, and pass it along as an argument

```bash
warn() {
  level="$1"
  echo "${@:2}" | 
      awk -v level="$level" -v RS="+" '
        BEGIN { align = length(level)+2 } 
        NR==1 { printf "%-*s%s\n", align, level":", $0; next } 
        { printf "%-*s%s\n", align, "", $0 }'
}
```

and call it as

```
warn "WARNING" "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." \
     "+Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow." \
     "+How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!"
```

produces

```
WARNING: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
         How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!
```

Works well according to the title you pass along e.g. `WARNING` or `NOTE`.

Answer (score -4):

Um, why not just:

```
warn="WARNING: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
         How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!"

note="NOTE: This happened.
      Foo bar."
```

Result:

```
$ echo "$warn"
WARNING: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
         How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!

$ echo "$note"
NOTE: This happened.
      Foo bar.
```

Or like this:

```
declare -A msg=(
[warn]="WARNING: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
         How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!"

[note]="NOTE: This happened.
      Foo bar."
)

$ echo "${msg[warn]}"
WARNING: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.
         How quickly daft jumping zebras vex!

$ echo "${msg[note]}"
NOTE: This happened.
      Foo bar.
```

Comment: Because that is incumbent on the coder (and future coders) to figure out the whitespace for each line manually, but more importantly wouldn't be robust against indentation changes.

Comment: Yes, future coders will have to figure out why you did this function to print simple text message instead of just print text message. Just KISS)